# Is it possible to get ACTION_DELETE intent callback

Tags: android

I used

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.any.app");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(intent);
```

to delete a package, but I can't get the callback or delete success event after the delete action complete.

I searched a lot but not a clue, is it possible to get the `ACTION_DELETE` callback ?

[image: The Chinese word "确定" on image means "confirm"]

The event trigger by the confirm button on the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834594/intent-package-added-not-registering).
The way to observe package installed or removed, is to add a broadcast to receive the intent.
Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED in Intent.See details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED.)

But be careful,Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED's API level is 14.
If your application is under 14, you can try this.
First,create a **BroadcastReceiver** "UninstallReceiver".Then **declare** it in AndroidManifest.xml.My declare is this

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.manager.Broadcast.UninstallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>"
```

When you send a Intent.ACTION_DELETE,if the app is uninstalled completely,you can receive a broadcast in your BroadcastReceiver,then you can do whatever you want.