# how to know android app is installing/downloading

Tags: android

I am developing an android app in which user earns points when he installs and runs the apps from play store. Now if user wants to earn pints then he has to install the some apps from play store...while installing the app from play store what is the status of app(installing/downloading)

In my Android app I want to know the status of an app. i.e app is installing or downloading

I found NotifyListenerservice...not sure it is for that only.

Please tell me how to achieve this.

Thanks,
Anjali

Comment: You may wish to explain in greater detail what "status of an app" and "app is installing or downloading" mean.

Comment: If you mean the status of your application in regards to it's current state on your phone (downloaded, installed, uninstalled, running, closed, etc), you are going to run into a number of issues. If you just want to know if the application is in the process of downloading something or installing something (from within the application) that is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

Use a BroadcastReceiver to see if it has been installed or removed, or whatever you want.

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.PackageChangeReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="99999998">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

You can find an example here [Intent PACKAGE_ADDED not registering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834594/intent-package-added-not-registering)

You can also use an AccessibilityService to validate if the app has been started, but you shouldnt abuse this for this use.

Answer (score 0):

**No** you can't check.. Your app can't be aware of being installed or it is downloaded.

The broadcast receivers will be initialized only after the manual launch of the application. Before that broadcast receivers are not actually listening. 
The application is in stopped state. The app needs a **manual launch**..

Answer (score 0):

@Anjali The problem which you are asking is called Conversion Tracking. You can find out more about this term on Google.

When app is installed on device then OS send a broadcast to the application which can be listen by application. Have a look at below code:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER")) {
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                String referrerString = extras.getString("referrer");
                //ReferrerString variable contain your data which was passed to your application. Now you can do whatever you want to like communicating with server etc.
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
```

Generally, If you are passing some unique parameter in the url to install the application then you will get those parameter in ReferrerString. Your play store link will look something like below:

http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=packagename**&referrer=yourdata**

You would need below manifest entries for it:

```
<receiver android:name="packagename.BoradcastReciverImplmentedClass" android:exported="true" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```