# geocoder getaddress from name not working in Samsung galaxy tab 2?

Tags: android, google-geocoder, galaxy-tab, android-backup-service

I am using Geocoder to get latitude and longitude of place in my app. `geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, maxResults)`is the method that I am using for this. It works fine in all the devices except for samsung galaxy tab 2 devices

code :

```
        @Override
        protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... params) {
            address = params[0];
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                return geocoder.getFromLocationName(params[0], 5);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

logcat :

```
02-24 21:23:27.568 D/BackupManagerService(  189): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.myapp flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
02-24 21:23:27.568 V/BackupManagerService(  189): addPackageParticipantsLocked: com.myapp
```

I think the problem is **addPackageParticipantsLocked** any suggestions would be really helpful thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515310/broadcast-receiver-for-package-added-not-working-from-android-3-1-onwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [This Link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009) i would like give you suggestion to Reboot your Device.
 **Many of People have solved this issue by Rebooting there Device.**
 you can also try the same. Give it a try. it may solve your Problem.

Hope it will Help.