# Android Google Maps V2 Running issue

Tags: android, google-maps

I am Working on Google Map. But When i run my code so it saying..

> Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED intent due to
>   initialization failure.

I can't understand this problem, what should I do?

Comment: post some code and stacktrace...

Answer (score 1):

i have solved this issue by copied my .apk into platform-tools and install .apk via command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a broadcast behavior change since Android 3.1, your app must be started before it can receive the app installation/removal intents. See kabuko's answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515310/broadcast-receiver-for-package-added-not-working-from-android-3-1-onwards).

Also check this thread:
[Intent PACKAGE_ADDED not registering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834594/intent-package-added-not-registering)